# Looping through div's in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
     $('#divs').children().each(
  function(){

   //Get Id's
   var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');
   alert(id);

  }
 );
```

With the markup of:

```
      <div id="divs">
     <div id="item_1">
         <div id="sub_1">
             ---
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

        <div id="item_2">
             <div id="sub_1">
                ---
             </div>
             <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Basically, it loops out twice for each id="item_" set... I just want it to count the item_1, item_2, etc. divs.  Not the sub_1, etc.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I ended up going with:

$('#divs').children(/[id_]/).each

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divs > div").each(
    function(){
        //your function
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sub select children: `$('#divs').children('[id^=item]')`